# Jquery validate existing input

Tags: jquery-validate

On a form input, i am setting the value that i receive from server side. The form input can be again submitted, but if the user doesn't change the input i.e., replace the input and place the same value again, the form should not be validated and alerted to the user, that the same value cannot be set again.

--
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var changeme = $('input[name=changeme]').val();
            $.validator.addMethod("mustchange", function (value, element) {
                if (value === changeme) {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }, "you must change this value");
            $('form').validate({ debug: true });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <div id="main">
        <input name="changeme" type="text" value="My name is bob" class="mustchange" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```